# reading a .txt file from a folder in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, ipython

```
directory =os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\udi\\pcm-audio") 
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r') 
            a = f.read() 
            if re.findall('\"status_code\": 0', a):
                print('Valid one') 
            else: 
                print('Invalid') 
        f.close()
```

I have to read only a .txt file from the folder, so I am doing as above. Later I am trying to print what I read. But I am not getting any output when I run the above program. Can someone help me what is the mistake in that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
```

that zetysz answered is right.
The problem is in the start directory path you give containing backslashes.

You can change that to forward slashes / instead of backslashes \ like this:

```
directory = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/sam/Desktop/pcm-audio")
```

or you can use double backslashes to quote them like this:

```
directory = os.path.normpath("C:\\Users\sam\\Desktop\\pcm-audio")
```

also use [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to normalize the path. You dont need [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) here, since you do not join anything.

So this should work:

```
import os

directory = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/sam/Desktop/pcm-audio")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
            a = f.read()
            print a
            f.close()
```

Comment: it is working with double slashes. thank you :) can you please tell me how to read a specific line from the .txt file ?

Comment: For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:
     `for line in f:
        print line,`

[read more](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) search for readlines

Comment: Example : If the .txt file as 200 lines of .txt. If I want to read a specific line with status code == 0 in the .txt file then how to do it ?. I modified my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
...  
f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')  
...
```

Replace the separator `/` with `\`(Python2), `\\` (Python3).

To read a specific line you can use `linecache`:

```
import linecache
linecache.getline(filename, linenumber)
```

Comment: It is not working. just getting a empty screen. I cant see anything on the screen.

Comment: it is working with double slashes. ty :) can you please tell me how to read a specific line from the .txt file ?

Comment: If I am looking for a word called status code == 0 in .txt file. There will be so many .txt file If the line number is different in different .txt file. then what to do ?

Comment: @Hemanth Venkatappa would you like to get `status code == ?` from text files ?

Comment: there is a status code line in the .txt file. Just I want to check that status code ==0 then it is valid else it is invalid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98083/discussion-between-hemanth-venkatappa-and-zetysz).