# How to replace a text with another text in several txt-files at the same time

Tags: python

I want to know how to replace a text with another text in several txt-files at the same time. I have several files with the name `S-n`, n = 1,...,29, and I want to keep the same name for the new txt files.

Here is the code that I've found through internet for one file at a time:

```
# creating a variable and storing the text
# that we want to search
search_text = "opt freq"
  
# creating a variable and storing the text
# that we want to add
replace_text = "LAN2DZ"
  
# Opening our text file in read only
# mode using the open() function
with open(r'S-1.txt', 'r') as file:
  
    # Reading the content of the file
    # using the read() function and storing
    # them in a new variable
    data = file.read()
  
    # Searching and replacing the text
    # using the replace() function
    data = data.replace(search_text, replace_text)
  
# Opening our text file in write only
# mode to write the replaced content
with open(r'S-1.txt', 'w') as file:
  
    # Writing the replaced data in our
    # text file
    file.write(data)
  
# Printing Text replaced
print("Text replaced")
```

Here is the error that I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/lenovo/Documents/ctcs/Python/Untitled-2.py", line 11, in  with open(r'S-1', 'r') as file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S-1'

Comment: What is not clear in that error you got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S-1'`  ? Copy&Paste code won't work, make sure you understand the code

Comment: Take all file names into `list` & try to `itterate` them over `one-by-one` .

Comment: @tturbo I put it in the same folder as the code but it still displays the same error

Comment: The error message in _not_ in line with the code you've posted: `open(r'S-1.txt', 'r')` vs  `open(r'S-1', 'r')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, to the error message you posted**

(`No such file or directory: 'S-1'`)

In short, your Python script cannot find the text file `S-1.txt` that you reference.

Check that your python script is next to your text file, like below:

```
  ├── Your_Main_Folder
  ├──── Your_Python_File.py
  └──── S-1.txt
```

The important part is that the text file is in the same folder or directory as your text file.

Alternatively, you can refer to the full path of your text file, if the text file(s) must be in another folder - The link below describes that approach a bit more:

[reading a .txt file from a folder in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307339/reading-a-txt-file-from-a-folder-in-python-script)

**To your second question, about processing a list of text files** -

You could try something like below to edit a list of `.txt` files:

```
# creating a variable and storing the text
# that we want to search
search_text = "opt freq"
  
# creating a variable and storing the text
# that we want to add
replace_text = "LAN2DZ"

# Text Files to Revise:
textFiles_ToEdit = ['S-1.txt']

# Loop over each text file in our list from above
for eachFile in textFiles_ToEdit:
    # Opening our text file in read only
    # mode using the open() function
    with open(eachFile, 'r') as file:
    
        # Reading the content of the file
        # using the read() function and storing
        # them in a new variable
        data = file.read()
    
        # Searching and replacing the text
        # using the replace() function
        data = data.replace(search_text, replace_text)
    
    # Opening our text file in write only
    # mode to write the replaced content
    with open(eachFile, 'w') as file:
    
        # Writing the replaced data in our
        # text file
        file.write(data)
  
# Printing Text replaced
print("Text replaced")
```

This assumes that the target text files are in the same folder/ directory as your python script - otherwise, you will need to adjust the pathing for your text files.